# XML Node Notation (XPath to dataframe in R)

Tags: r, xml, xpath, dataframe

I am fairly new to R and am trying to read an XML file and transform it into a data frame in R using XPath. I have found a solution transforming the file into a list from where on I would be able to handle it. However, I need my program to run relatively fast. 
I have checked the tutorial on w3school.com (http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_nodes.asp)on XPath, however they don't explain the notation I find in my XML file. 
I want to make a data frame containing the different customers and their attributes. The beginning of the file is not needed in my calculations.

Following is an excerpt of the file:

```
$config
<config>
  <competition id="0" name="0" pomId="1.3.1-SNAPSHOT" timeslotLength="60" bootstrapTimeslotCount="336" bootstrapDiscardedTimeslots="24" timeslotsOpen="24" deactivateTimeslotsAhead="1" minimumOrderQuantity="0.01" timezoneOffset="-6" latitude="45" simulationRate="720" simulationModulo="3600000">
<description/>
<simulationBaseTime>
  <iMillis>1255132800000</iMillis>
</simulationBaseTime>
<broker>default broker</broker>
<customer id="4097" name="HighIncome-2_8" population="1" powerType="ELECTRIC_VEHICLE" customerClass="SMALL" controllableKW="-3.3" upRegulationKW="-3.3" downRegulationKW="3.3" storageCapacity="85.0" multiContracting="false" canNegotiate="false"/>
<customer id="4100" name="HighIncome-2_9" population="1" powerType="ELECTRIC_VEHICLE" customerClass="SMALL" controllableKW="-3.3" upRegulationKW="-3.3" downRegulationKW="3.3" storageCapacity="60.0" multiContracting="false" canNegotiate="false"/>
<customer id="4103" name="HighIncome-2_10" population="1" powerType="ELECTRIC_VEHICLE" customerClass="SMALL" controllableKW="-3.3" upRegulationKW="-3.3" downRegulationKW="3.3" storageCapacity="60.0" multiContracting="false" canNegotiate="false"/>
<customer id="4106" name="HighIncome-2_11" population="1" powerType="ELECTRIC_VEHICLE" customerClass="SMALL" controllableKW="-3.3" upRegulationKW="-3.3" downRegulationKW="3.3" storageCapacity="85.0" multiContracting="false" canNegotiate="false"/>
```

How do I refer to each customers? Are they an attribute node, an attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XML, there are two structural types that hold values:

1. element (also known as node or tag), enclosed with angular brackets whose value is held between the opening `<element>` and closing `</element>`
2. attribute prefixed with `@` whose value is assigned with equal operator

For your specific XML, *customer* is the element with *id*, *name*, *population*, *powerType*, *customerClass*, *controllableKW*, *upRegulationKW*, *downRegulationKW*, *storageCapacity*, *multiContracting*, and *canNegotiate* as attributes.

In R XML module, to extract a set of values from `xpathSApply()`, its XPath 1.0 function, you would specify the `fun` argument as *xmlValue* for element value and *xmlAttrs* for attribute values. From there you can manipulate the outputted list or matrix for data frame migration. And specifically for your needs, you simply can extract data into matrix and transpose to final data frame. The [double forward slash](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-xmldsig-xpath-20110421/) is used in XPath expression to find anywhere in document a specific location, here customers.

```
library(XML)
xmlstr <- '<config>
             <competition id="0" name="0" pomId="1.3.1-SNAPSHOT" timeslotLength="60" bootstrapTimeslotCount="336" bootstrapDiscardedTimeslots="24" timeslotsOpen="24" deactivateTimeslotsAhead="1" minimumOrderQuantity="0.01" timezoneOffset="-6" latitude="45" simulationRate="720" simulationModulo="3600000">
               <description/>
               <simulationBaseTime>
                  <iMillis>1255132800000</iMillis>
               </simulationBaseTime>
               <broker>default broker</broker>
               <customer id="4097" name="HighIncome-2_8" population="1" powerType="ELECTRIC_VEHICLE" customerClass="SMALL" controllableKW="-3.3" upRegulationKW="-3.3" downRegulationKW="3.3" storageCapacity="85.0" multiContracting="false" canNegotiate="false"/>
               <customer id="4100" name="HighIncome-2_9" population="1" powerType="ELECTRIC_VEHICLE" customerClass="SMALL" controllableKW="-3.3" upRegulationKW="-3.3" downRegulationKW="3.3" storageCapacity="60.0" multiContracting="false" canNegotiate="false"/>
               <customer id="4103" name="HighIncome-2_10" population="1" powerType="ELECTRIC_VEHICLE" customerClass="SMALL" controllableKW="-3.3" upRegulationKW="-3.3" downRegulationKW="3.3" storageCapacity="60.0" multiContracting="false" canNegotiate="false"/>
               <customer id="4106" name="HighIncome-2_11" population="1" powerType="ELECTRIC_VEHICLE" customerClass="SMALL" controllableKW="-3.3" upRegulationKW="-3.3" downRegulationKW="3.3" storageCapacity="85.0" multiContracting="false" canNegotiate="false"/>
             </competition>
           </config>'    
xml <- xmlParse(xmlstr)

# MATRIX OF CUSTOMER ATTRIBS
customerAttribs <- xpathSApply(doc=xml, path="//customer",  xmlAttrs)

# TRANSPOSE TO DATA FRAME
df <- data.frame(t(customerAttribs))

#     id            name population        powerType customerClass controllableKW  \
# 1 4097  HighIncome-2_8          1 ELECTRIC_VEHICLE         SMALL           -3.3
# 2 4100  HighIncome-2_9          1 ELECTRIC_VEHICLE         SMALL           -3.3
# 3 4103 HighIncome-2_10          1 ELECTRIC_VEHICLE         SMALL           -3.3
# 4 4106 HighIncome-2_11          1 ELECTRIC_VEHICLE         SMALL           -3.3
#   upRegulationKW downRegulationKW storageCapacity multiContracting canNegotiate
# 1           -3.3              3.3            85.0            false        false
# 2           -3.3              3.3            60.0            false        false
# 3           -3.3              3.3            60.0            false        false
# 4           -3.3              3.3            85.0            false        false
```